# GridView to Excel export with ClosedXML no column names

Tags: asp.net, gridview, closedxml

I am generating a gridview with the following code;

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CssClass="gridview" >
           <HeaderStyle CssClass="fixedHeader "  Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Affiliation" HeaderText="Affiliation" SortExpression="Affiliation" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MailingAddress" HeaderText="Mailing Address" SortExpression="MailingAddress" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="MembershipCategory" HeaderText="Membership Category" SortExpression="MembershipCategory" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="MemberApproved" HeaderText="Membership Approval" SortExpression="MemberApproved" />
            
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Then I am using ClosedXML to export the gridview to excel with a button click:

```
      protected void ExportExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("GridView_Data");
        foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(cell.Text);
        }
     
      
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = row.Cells[i].Text;
                //dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = ((row.Cells[i].Controls[0]) as DataBoundLiteralControl).Text.Trim();
            }
        }
        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename= Group_Members_" + DateTime.Now + ".xlsx");
            using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
```

The problem i am running to is that the generated excel file column names are Column1, Column2 etc and not the column names as in the grid. Any idea why and how to fix this please?
AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(GridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText);
        }
```